# jQuery - CSS - function - Trying to change class of current tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, addclass

I'll be quick and simple about this:

Here's my **HTML**

```
<div id="headerVideoControls" class="overlayElement">
  <div id="videoMuteUnmute" onclick="muteUnmuteVideo('headerVideo')">mute button</div>
</div>
```

*Edited*

```
<video id="headerVideo" loop muted preload="auto" poster="css\img\headerVideoPreview.jpg">
  <source src="uploads/video/headerVideo_2.mp4" type="video/mp4"> 
</video>
```

Here's my **jQuery**

```js
function muteUnmuteVideo(id) { 
      activeVideo = document.getElementById(id);
if (activeVideo.muted) {
    activeVideo.muted = false;
    $(this).addClass('unMuted'); 
} else {
    activeVideo.muted = true;  
    $(this).addClass('muted');

}}
```

What i'm trying to achieve is adding class to the videoMuteUnmute/videoPlayPause that changes background image, to show different icons for different stages **mute**/**not muted**/**playing**/**paused**
Th only things that work are the controls. But not changing class.

Comment: Where's the element with the id `headerVideo` ?

Comment: Forgot about that, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your `this` keyword in `muteUnmuteVideo` function.

Your `muteUnmuteVideo` function is defined in the global scope. When you use `event attributes` such as `onclick`, what happens is that the function is called in that scope, meaning that the `this` keyword refers to Window object. Basically it's not different as if you call it outside of an event handler, it just executes the function as it was defined. You have a reference to the `event`, but `this` will point to the Window object.

You have a couple of choices, first one would be to use `event.target` instead of `this`. The `event` will have a reference to the element that was clicked. Like this:

```
    $(event.target).addClass('unMuted');
```

Or, you could use `addEventListener` instead of the `onclick attribute`, which is recommended since it keeps your layout and behaviors separated, which is usually a better approach. This way, `this` will refer to the element that was clicked. Like this:

```
    document.getElementById('videoMuteUnmute').addEventListener('click', muteUnmuteVideo)
```

You could also define `onclick` property of your element, then `this` will refer to the element. Like this:

```
    document.getElementById('videoMuteUnmute').onclick = muteUnmuteVideo
```

Also, you might want to use `toggleClass`, in your current setup, once you click on your button, you'll always have both classes, since they're never removed.

Comment: This actually owrked. I used ' $(event.target).addClass('unMuted');'

Answer (score 1):

By `$(this)` you are not referring the `currentVideo` object, use the following code:

```
function muteUnmuteVideo(id) { 
   activeVideo = $("#"+id);
   if (activeVideo.muted) {
      activeVideo.muted = false;
      activeVideo.addClass('unMuted'); 
   } else {
      activeVideo.muted = true;  
      activeVideo.addClass('muted');
}}
```

With  `$("#"+id)` you will get the right element by id and then change its class accordingly.

**Note :**

In the case you use only  `addClass()`  without removing it, you may have both `muted` and `unMuted` classes, so better use `.attr("class", ...)` :

```js
function muteUnmuteVideo(id) {
  var activeVideo = $("#" + id);
  if (activeVideo.attr("muted") == "true") {
    activeVideo.attr("muted", "false");
    activeVideo.attr("class", "unMuted");
    alert("unMuted");
  } else {
    activeVideo.attr("muted", "true");
    activeVideo.attr("class", "muted");
    alert("Muted");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="headerVideoControls" class="overlayElement">
  <div id="videoMuteUnmute" onclick="muteUnmuteVideo('headerVideo')">mute button</div>
</div>

<video id="headerVideo" loop muted preload="auto" poster="css\img\headerVideoPreview.jpg">
  <source src="uploads/video/headerVideo_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And that will do the trick for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try if(activeVideo.muted == true)

Comment: code only works with **=** but with **==** video is not muted, but addClass() does not work.

Comment: Actually i m trying to say in your if statement check if (activeVideo.muted== true) works instead of just if (activeVideo.muted)....